# Add to textarea maxlength with a button

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea

I've been trying to use javascript to add to a textarea's maxlength with a button. What it currently does is it counts how many characters are left that you can type. I want it to also have a button that will add 20 to it. However, the button doesn't add 20 to the maxlength. Here's my code:

**Javascript:**

```
var el_t = document.getElementById('textarea');
var length = el_t.getAttribute("maxlength");
var el_c = document.getElementById('count');
el_c.innerHTML = length;
el_t.onkeyup = function () {
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = (length - this.value.length);
};
function addLength() {
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = (document.getElementById('textarea').maxlength + 20);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="textarea" maxlength="99" placeholder="Type..."></textarea>
<span id="count"></span>
<button onclick="addLength()">Add to character limit!</button>
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What problem are you having?

Comment: The javascript function won't work, it doesn't add 20 to the textarea's maxlength -- I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. Handles the recount

**Javascript**

```
var el_t = document.getElementById('textarea');
var length = function(){ return el_t.getAttribute("maxlength");};
var el_c = document.getElementById('count');
el_c.innerHTML = length();

el_t.onkeyup = function () {
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = (length() - this.value.length);
};

function addLength() {
  var count = parseInt(length()) + 20;
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count;
  el_t.setAttribute("maxlength",count);
  triggerEvent(el_t,"keyup");
}

function triggerEvent(el, type){
   if ('createEvent' in document) {
        // modern browsers, IE9+
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {
        // IE 8
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textarea" maxlength="99" placeholder="Type..."></textarea>
<span id="count"></span>
<button onclick="addLength()">Add to character limit!</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, I see what's going on, I messed up a bit. Thank you!!

Comment: How can I add an if statement to test for the maxlength being < 0, and set it to zero? For some reason, whatever I try isn't working. I understand it's quite basic, but for some reason, this _one_ isn't working.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the scenario when would the maxlength be negative?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I also used what you gave me to make a "subtract" button.

Comment: var count = parseInt(length()) - 20;
count = count < 0 ? 0 : count;
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count;
el_t.setAttribute("maxlength",count);
triggerEvent(el_t,"keyup");

Comment: Yes, I have that, but now the problem is the maxLength goes into the negatives. How can I make an if statement to test for it being below zero, then putting it at zero?

Comment: Use a ternary operator: count = count < 0 ? 0 : count; Then assign count like before.

Answer (score 0):

the maxLength attribute should have a capital L, whereas yours has a lowercase l. Here is an example:

HTML

```
<textarea col='30' rows='4' maxlength='50' id='t1'></textarea>
<button onclick='maxchange()'>SUBMIT</button><br>
<div id='d1'></div>
```

Javascript

```
function maxchange() {
  document.getElementById('t1').maxLength +=5;
  document.getElementById('d1').innerHTML=document.getElementById('t1').maxLength;
}
```

Comment: It didn't quite work; the number I have on the side that says how many characters are left gets messed up (ex. goes into the negatives)

Comment: Do you have an if statement that checks for negative numbers? if(x < 0) maxLength = 0; for example

Comment: No; I'll add one.